# Ask about inference on Graphdb

Tags: graphdb

my ontology about social network. And we have simple SWRL rules two people(?p1,?p2) workInOrg Org(?org) => colleagueOf(?p1,?p2) and if thier colleague, one people workInOrg => the other person also works in that Org. I also build OWL Axioms but it cant take affect on Graphdb. Another try is that i wrote a custom rule, but Graphdb only allow to choose one Rule (In my case "owrl2-rl") and my custom rule only take affect when combining on this rule OWL2-RL. Is there a way to use combine rules and write rule effienctly?

SHACL validation is good. Does graphdb has OWL constraint validation ??? (ex: domain-range validation ?)

Thanks.

Comment: GraphDB do not provide means to combine different rulesets for inference. But You can clone the owl2-rl ruleset (located in <dist>/config/rules) and modify it by adding your additional rules there and set that as ruleset of your repository

Answer (score 1):

Damyan's comment above provides the answer

One can do this also with OWL2 RL and property chains (see https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-profiles/#OWL_2_RL in https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-profiles/#OWL_2_RL). This would not require custom rules, but inference will be a bit slower

This is how it can work:
:worksIn owl:inverseOf :employerOf 
:colleagueOf owl:propertyChainAxiom  ( :worksIn :employerOf ) .
:worksIn owl:propertyChainAxiom  ( :colleagueOf :worksIn ) .